# GroupBy in fs2?

Tags: scala, fs2

Is there a function like [`groupBy`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/groupBy) (from rxjs) in fs2?

I'd like to use it to covert stream of messages to stream of streams with messages from each chat depends on message's chatId.

Example in rxjs:

```js
function chats(messages$: Observable<Message>): Observable<GroupedObservable<number, Message>> {
  return messages$.pipe(groupBy((m) => m.chatId));
}
```

Comment: I believe a `Topic` is what you need: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/co.fs2/fs2-docs_2.13/3.5.0/fs2/concurrent/Topic.html - PS: You may want to ask in the **Discord** server as well: https://discord.com/channels/632277896739946517/632310980449402880

Comment: Closest I see is [`groupAdjacentBy`](https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/co/fs2/fs2-core_2.13/2.5.11/fs2-core_2.13-2.5.11-javadoc.jar/!/fs2/Stream.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't built into the library, but it's been implemented in various libraries. For example, here's a version of it from [fs2-aws](https://github.com/laserdisc-io/fs2-aws/blob/b39e74f50498dcf16a63b474477f6887f5fb4484/fs2-aws-core/src/main/scala/fs2/aws/core/kinesis/package.scala) (under the MIT license)

```
package fs2.aws

import cats.effect.{Concurrent, Ref}
import cats.implicits.*
import cats.effect.std.Queue
import fs2.{Pipe, Stream}

package object core {

  /** Helper flow to group elements of a stream into K substreams.
    * Grows with the number of distinct 'K' selectors
    *
    * Start with an empty Map of keys to queues
    * On element received, invoke the selector function to yield the key denoting which queue this element belongs to
    * If we already have an existing queue for that respective key, append the element lifted in an Option to the queue
    * If a queue for that key does not exist, create a new queue, append it to the queue mapping, and then enqueue the element lifted in an Option
    * For each queue, drain the queue yielding a stream of elements
    * After the stream has been emptied, enqueue a single None to the queue so that the stream halts
    *
    *  @tparam F effect type of the fs2 stream
    *  @param selector partitioning function based on the element
    *  @return a FS2 pipe producing a new sub-stream of elements grouped by the selector
    */
  def groupBy[F[_], A, K](
      selector: A => F[K]
  )(implicit F: Concurrent[F]): Pipe[F, A, (K, Stream[F, A])] = { in =>
    Stream.eval(Ref.of[F, Map[K, Queue[F, Option[A]]]](Map.empty)).flatMap { queueMap =>
      val cleanup =
        queueMap.get.flatMap(_.values.toList.traverse_(_.offer(None)))

      (in ++ Stream.exec(cleanup))
        .evalMap { elem =>
          (selector(elem), queueMap.get).mapN { (key, queues) =>
            queues
              .get(key)
              .fold {
                for {
                  newQ <- Queue.unbounded[F, Option[A]] // Create a new queue
                  _    <- queueMap.modify(queues => (queues + (key -> newQ), queues))
                  // Enqueue the element lifted into an Option to the new queue
                  _ <- newQ.offer(elem.some)
                } yield (key -> Stream.fromQueueNoneTerminated(newQ, 100)).some
              }(_.offer(elem.some).as(None))
          }.flatten
        }
        .unNone
        .onFinalize(cleanup)
    }
  }
}
```